# HDMI doesn't work on Acer Aspire R3600

Tags: hdmi, cable, acer-aspire

My HDMI cable won't connect when I plug one end into the HDMI slot on the Acer Aspire R3600 and the other into a Samsung DVD player.

What could be causing this?  Is there anything else I should be doing to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the R3600 is able to accept HDMI in, it's only for displaying video out. You will need to conenct the DVD player directly to your display device to see output from it.

Comment: I don't think most computer are capable of that.

Comment: @PeterMaxwell Most computers are not. I had a laptop (Lenovo Ideapad) which allowed you to do pass-through input via VGA to the laptop screen, but that's no where near as complex as HDMI in.

Comment: I've always wanted to be able to do that, but have never seen a computer capable of that.

Comment: @PeterMaxwell I had an IdeaPad Y710, and there was a little switch beside the VGA port which toggled it back and forth between VGA-in and VGA-out (in case you were interested).

Comment: Wow, it sounds magical.